# grab the option tag value y pass into an array

Tags: jquery, select, return-value

I can't grab the option tag value pass into first position array. I am not sure if I have to use `parseInt()` over the option tag value. I want to turn data array first position `(data[4])` into option tag value defines for `$(this).attr('value')`.

Here the code:

**`HTML`**

```
<select id="sel" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="1">Alejandro / Sergio</option>
    <option value="3">Ángel / Pilar</option>
</select>
```

**`JQUERY`**

```
var ctx = $('#myChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue"],
                datasets: [{
                    data: [4, 2],
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                    ],
                }]
            },
        });

$('#sel').on('change', function(){
    ***var data =  parseInt($(this).attr('value'));
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data[0] = data;***
    myChart.update();
});
```

Comment: do select the answer as correct if it worked for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a dropdown it should be

```
 var data = parseInt($(this).val());
```

rather than

```
 var data = parseInt($(this).attr('value'))
```

`select-dropdown` does not have any attribute `value`, but instead the `option` tag inside the `select-dropdown` has the attribute `value` and to get the selected option's value you simply do `$('#element_id').val()` or `$(this).val()` inside the click event

Comment: Your right men, thanks a lot. I can´t leave you a vote because my stackoverflow reputation is not enough to do it

Comment: thats ok no issue just select the answer as correct if it worked for you @Jmainol